# grep an exact word in 2 files then write result into a file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grep

I tried doing that :

```
grep FallenHope DATABASE1.txt DATABASE2.sql >> breached.txt
```

I want to lookup the FallenHope username in 2 databases but they are not in the same format and for other usernames it will just give a bunch of usernames derived from the original username.

The database formats are:

```
1   USERNAME    mail@gmail.com      hashedpass
```

and

```
USERNAME:mail@hotmail.com:ip:ip:hashedpass
```

I also tried doing

```
grep -w FallenHope DATABASE1.txt DATABASE2.sql >> breached.txt
```

but it still does not work

any ways to do it?

Comment: `grep -w` works perfectly for this case (tested it on my system)? Can you give us an example of what `grep -w` returns?

Comment: yes just 1 minute pls

Comment: DATABASE2.sql:Trevor:ricardo_trevas@hotmail.com:187.79.167.96:187.79.139.160:71ae7d9f33c19cf0f9ef8dd27b83e8a8:CrbukP
DATABASE2.sql:Trevor White:helix90@gmail.com:192.168.0.199:::
DATABASE2.sql:Trevor-1234:Seahitcht@yahoo.ca:70.78.214.49:70.78.214.49:6d34a93421e12affd2f817a0bfeed25c:lyswC2
DATABASE2.sql:Trevorlebosse:Trevor@hotmail.fr:10.92.20.29:10.92.20.29:608028ecb0eaeb0add6ac1e6e5f44810:am5tgE

Comment: for this example it is showing 3 usernames that stars with Trevor (Treover and Trevor-1234 also Trevorlebosse)

Comment: Add this to your question, no comment.

Answer (score 0):

This is what `man 1 grep` says about `grep -w`:

> `-w`, `--word-regexp`
>   Select only those lines containing matches that form whole words. The test is that the matching substring must either be at the beginning of the line, or preceded by a non-word constituent character. Similarly, it must be either at the end of the line or followed by a non-word constituent character. Word constituent characters are letters, digits, and the underscore. […]

There are at least two problems with your approach based on `grep FallenHope` or `grep -w FallenHope`:

1. There's no guarantee the matching is against the `USERNAME` field. E.g. `FallenHope@…` e-mail address does match (and `-w` doesn't help because `@` is a non-word constituent character).
2. `FallenHope-12345` does match (and `-w` doesn't help because `-` is a non-word constituent character).

You need to *tailor* the `grep` pattern to fit each format *separately*. This seems easier for the second one.

> ```
> USERNAME:mail@hotmail.com:ip:ip:hashedpass
> ```

The following `grep` will search for `FallenHope` at the very beginning of the line. Trailing `:` in the pattern makes matching `FallenHope-1` or `FallenHopes` impossible.

```
grep '^FallenHope:' DATABASE2.sql
```

Add redirection (`>> breached.txt`) after you make sure my code does what you want.

And for the first format

> ```
> 1   USERNAME    mail@gmail.com      hashedpass
> ```

something like this should work:

```
grep '^[[:digit:]]*[[:blank:]]*FallenHope[[:blank:]]' DATABASE1.txt
```

It searches for zero or more digits at the beginning of the line, followed by zero or more blanks, followed by `FallenHope`, followed by a blank. You may prefer "one or more" better than "zero or more" but if the format is strict then "zero or more" should be fine.

Anyway you need to adjust the pattern to the format. If there are quirks I didn't anticipate and you know them, adjust the pattern accordingly.

---

I think `awk` can do this as well. The tool is designed to work with *fields*, this approach seems perfect for the job. Example code:

```
awk      '$2=="FallenHope"' DATABASE1.txt
awk -F : '$1=="FallenHope"' DATABASE2.sql
```